# How to override a part of the styles assigned automatically to GMaps Custom Controls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a custom control for use with Google Maps Javascript API, however on adding it some CSS rules of added by Google (the following):

```
element.style {
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 105px;
}
```

> Note that `element.style` means inline styling. See comment after [mrunde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3696443/mrunde)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40358644/5961780).

However `right: 105px;` conflicts with my existing rules and the control ends up looking different.

I tried setting it to `initial` by `$('#search').css('right', 'initial');`, but GMaps re-adds the conflicting property as soon document (browser window) is resized.

---

Code to add custom control (requested by [mrunde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3696443/mrunde)):

```
function addSearchControl(map) {
  $('#searchPanel').hide();
  $('#searchControl').click(function() {$('#searchPanel').toggle(500);});
  $('#search').get(0).index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push($('#search').get(0));
  $('#search').css('right', 'initial');
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code where you add the custom control?

Comment: @mrunde added code.